# Equivalence of Lie subalgebras, within a (irreducible) representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Lie subalgebras inside simple Lie algebras (of type ABCDEFG) have been classified up to equivalence, and linear equivalence (by Dynkin et al). How does one classify embeddings of a Lie algebra h inside a Lie algebra g, where the equivalence relation is given by saying that embeddings are ('adjoint') equivalent when they are conjugate in the adjoint representation of g ? (Thus, equivalence, and linear equivalence imply (adjoint) equivalence, but not the other way around.) More generally, how does one classify embeddings of subalgebras up to equivalence in a (=one) given irreducible representation ?

Comment: Lie subalgebras of Lie algebras have not been classified for Lie algebras (only maximal subalgebras of complex semisimple ones of finite dimension).

Comment: Question modified to reflect that I wished to ask the question within the context of simple Lie algebras of type ABCDEFG.

Comment: Dietrich's comment is well-taken and points to a fundamental difficulty with this kind of broad question: every finite dimensional Lie algebra embeds in some general linear algebra by Ado/Iwasawa theorems, so a lot of Lie algebras embed in the trace zero subalgebra (which is simple in most characteristics and acts irreducibly on the underlying vector space).

Answer (score 3):

As peoples' comments suggest, it is perhaps somewhat ambitious to hope for a classification of all Lie subalgebras of a given complex simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. However, Jacobson and Morozov have an answer concerning embeddings of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ into $\mathfrak{g}$.

Given a nilpotent orbit $\mathcal{O}\subseteq\mathfrak{g}$, one can find an $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-triple $(e,h,f)$ for which the nilpositive element $e$ lies in $\mathcal{O}$. This establishes a correspondence between the nilpotent orbits in $\mathfrak{g}$ and the adjoint-conjugacy classes of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-triples in $\mathfrak{g}$. The conjugacy classes of embeddings of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ into $\mathfrak{g}$ then correspond to the non-zero nilpotent orbits. There are finitely many of the latter.

Comment: Thanks, this does answer my question for the adjoint representation.